# ng2-smart-table derived column

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

I need to create a custom column in ng2-smart-table by calculating values of two columns.

I tried using valuePrepareFunction() but it wont work

```
    OrderQuantity:{
      title: 'OrderQuantity',
    },
    UnitPrice:{
      title: 'UnitPrice',
    },
    Total:{
      title: 'Total',
      type: 'custom',
      //Need to get total by : OrderQuantity*UnitPrice
    },
```

I need to get the total value by = OrderQuantity*UnitPrice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned you could do this by using the valuePrepareFunction in the ng2-smart-table.

As per the document this function will be invoked with 2 parameters: cell, row. Therefore you could simple use this as follows.

```
settings = {
columns: {
OrderQuantity:{
      title: 'OrderQuantity',
    },
    UnitPrice:{
      title: 'UnitPrice',
    },
    Total:{
      title: 'Total',
      valuePrepareFunction :(cell, row) =>{
          return row.OrderQuantity * row.UnitPrice;
     } 
    }
}
}
```